# Where are folders and images on the iPhone?[swift]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiimage

I am adding folders and images in `Assets.xcassets` of Xcode.

[image]

Where is the folder or image of `Assets.xcassets` stored on the iPhone when testing the actual machine with Xcode?

Also, I would like to know how to check whether the folder and image of `Assets.xcaassets` is installed in iPhone storage place right after launching the application.

Ultimately I would like to install the image in my AWS on the iPhone of the user of the application at the first launch of the application.

I would like to reduce the file size of the application.

Adding images to the iPhone of the user of the application is not a malicious purpose.

And I do not know the best way.

Comment: Check the ipa fiel. It has .car file that holds all the images and there are 3rd party tools on git hub that can show you the content of the car file

Comment: Thank you...I fixed the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The images are compiled by Xcode and a file called `Assets.car` (CoreUI archive) is created.

The file is then bundled in the ipa file created when you export the app.

If you uncompress the ipa (it's a simple zip file) you can see the car file inside the application packet.

Comment: Thank you.I fixed the sentences...For example...Is it possible to uncompress the ipa file inside the iPhone of the application user and refer to the inside of Assets.car?

Comment: Do you want to access the Assets.car file when running the application on the iPhone? No, it's not possible.

Comment: You can put the images in AWS but then you should download the images and save them in another directory of the app (e.g. the document directory). Or you can use some framework to download and cache the images like SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.

Comment: I am a beginner so I've never used a third party library.
It is difficult for me to use a third party library, but I will try it.
Thank you for your good advice.